# нужно чтобы программа выдавала первую строку, удаляла её и в следующий раз, при запросе строки, уже вторая шла, которая становилось первой

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня довольно простая задача, но че-то не очень думается, поэтому хочу у вас спросить. Вот у меня есть файл где примерно 100 строк,нужно чтобы программа выдавала первую строку, удаляла её и в следующий раз, при запросе строки, уже вторая шла, ну она бы первой становилось и отправлялась. Не подскажите?
Спасибо

Comment: покажите пожалуйста, что у вас есть и что вы пытались попробовать сделать.

Comment: ничего :(. Я не могу понять как это сделать, я думаю нужно брать txt файл, читать из него строку, она должна отправиться, удалиться из файла и при следующей отправке строки, отправлялась уже новая, ну вторая строка, которая стала первой типо

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

print(lines[0])

with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что эффективней и надежней будет хранить в соседнем файле позицию, с которой надо читать файл со строками в следующий раз. Иначе нужно каждый раз читать и писать все строки.